# How to add two images one in the right and other in the left side of the input textbox?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I've the following tags

```
<input id="date" class="mandatory datepicker" type="date" name="Date"></input>
 <input id="name" class="mandatory" type="text" name="Name"></input>
```

What I want to do is to have a common CSS background image for two fields on the left side which I am able to do using the mandatory class and have an unique CSS background image on the right side for the date field using datepicker class along with the common CSS.

What I want is [image]

What I get is  [image]

So can I do that?

Below are the CSS codes which I tried but couldn't get what I wanted.

```
.mandatory {
    background: #FFFFFF url(http://www.freecakefreecake.com/blog/wp-content/themes/Aggregate/epanel/shortcodes/images/list-dot.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: left;
}

.mandatory.datepicker {
    background: #FFFFFF url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Dot1.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: right;
    }
```

Is the datepicker image overlapping the mandatory image? If so how do I solve this issue?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kumareloaded/aybghsfp/

Comment: i don't understand what you want can you add a draw of the final result please? you will probability need labels or a parent to wrap them

Comment: I've attached an image. Please have a look.

Comment: where are the inputs on the image?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that?

Comment: i mean you are using 2 inputs but on the image i can see only one with two background images red and green. this is how you markup looks like http://jsfiddle.net/e7cazL1g/

Comment: I have updated the question with the respective pictorial representation. Now I think you can understand my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your valuable inputs.
I was able to get the solution by using the following CSS.

```
.mandatory {
    background: #FFFFFF url(http://www.freecakefreecake.com/blog/wp-content/themes/Aggregate/epanel/shortcodes/images/list-dot.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: left;
}

.mandatory.datepicker {
    background-image: url(http://www.freecakefreecake.com/blog/wp-content/themes/Aggregate/epanel/shortcodes/images/list-dot.png), url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Dot1.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-position: left, right;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kumareloaded/jcpLp492/

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE DUE TO COMMENT**

```css
input{position: relative}
.mandatory {
    background: #FFFFFF url(http://www.freecakefreecake.com/blog/wp-content/themes/Aggregate/epanel/shortcodes/images/list-dot.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: left;
}

.mandatory.datepicker {
    background: #FFFFFF url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/99/Dot1.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: right;
    text-indent: 4px
    }
.mandatory.datepicker:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFFFFF url(http://www.freecakefreecake.com/blog/wp-content/themes/Aggregate/epanel/shortcodes/images/list-dot.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: left;
    width: 12px;
    height: 14px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<input id="date" class="mandatory datepicker" type="date" name="Date" />
 <input id="name" class="mandatory" type="text" name="Name" />
```

**UPDATE:** change your markup to this then (***for typing reasons they have to be outside the box***)

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0}
form{
    padding: 40px
}
[class=name]{
    margin: 0 20px 0 80px
}
[class=date],[class=name],[class=submit]{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 160px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative
}
input[id=name],input[id=date]{
    width: 100%
}

[type=submit]{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    
}
label[for=date],label[for=name]{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: -32px;
    top: 2px;
    border-radius: 50%
}
[class=date]:before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    right: -32px;
    top: 2px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%
}
input:valid + label[for=date],input:valid + label[for=name]{
    background: green
}

input:invalid + label[for=date],input:invalid + label[for=name]{
    background: red
}
```

```html
<form>
    <div class=date>
        <input id=date class="mandatory datepicker" type=date name=Date required />
        <label for=date></label>
    </div>
    
    <div class=name>
        <input id=name class=mandatory type=text name=Name required />
        <label for=name></label>
    </div>
    <div class=submit>
        <input type=submit value=validate />
    </div>
</form>
```

you can not style inputs easily that is why you should use label since they are going together

```css
label{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: pointer; margin-right: 10px
}
label[for=date]:after{
    background: red
}
label[for=name]:after{
    background: green
}
label:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0px;    
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 4px solid #333
}
```

```html
<label for=date></label>
<input id=date class="mandatory datepicker" type=date name=Date />
<label for=name></label>
<input id=name class=mandatory type=text name=Name />
```

Comment: Thanks but what I need is to have two images inside the textbox(date) date and only one image inside textbox(text)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts but still I find this bit too complicated than what I want. I've provided a fiddle. And sample images of how the textbox should look. Please have a look.

Comment: Thanks, I still can't see both the images in the first textbox on your fiddle. BTW I've figured it out and it was so simple. Check out my answer here. Anyways thanks a lot for your time and efforts. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
.mandatory {
    background: #FFFFFF url(../images/mandatory.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: left;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
}

.mandatory.datepicker:after {
    content:'';
    display:block;
    width:10px; /*Change accordinlgly*/
    height:10px; /*Change accordinlgly*/
    position:absolute;
    top:5px; /*Change accordinlgly*/
    right:5px; /*Change accordinlgly*/
    background: url(../images/datepicker.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using `display:inline-block` property for both the images.

```
.mandatory {
    background: #FFFFFF url(../images/mandatory.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: left;
    display:inline-block;
}

.mandatory.datepicker {
    background: #FFFFFF url(../images/datepicker.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
    background-position: right;
    displya:inline-block;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.input {
    background: url(assets/Symbol39-2-min.png) no-repeat right center, 
                url(assets/Symbol38-2-min.png) no-repeat left center;
}
```